# Запись значений Google Sheets на отдельный лист

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть "Лист_1" в котором параметры в ячейках A1,A2,...A10 меняются с периодичностью 1 раз в 10 минут (подтягиваются через importhtml с триггером 10 мин)

Мне нужно, чтобы в "Листе_2" раз в 10 минут создавалась новая строка со значениями A1,A2,...A10 из "Листа_1" и отдельная ячейка с временем создания этой строки.
Проще говоря, мне нужно записывать параметры из "Листа_1" в "Лист_2" с периодичностью 1 раз в 10 минут.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скрипт для Google Sheets:

```
function appendData() {
  // Определение текущей даты и времени
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  // Получение данных из "Листа_1"
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Лист_1");
  var data = sheet1.getRange("A1:A10").getValues();

  // Добавление данных и времени в "Лист_2"
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Лист_2");
  data.push([time]);
  sheet2.appendRow(data);
}
```

Как подключить скрипт:

Откройте Google Sheets, выберите "Инструменты" - "Редактор скриптов".Добавьте новый скрипт нажав `"+ Новый скрипт"`. Вставьте скрипт и в окно редактора и сохраните. Запустите `appendData()` щелкнув по ней и нажав кнопку `"Запустить"`.   нажмите на `"Триггеры"` вверху редактора и на кнопку `"+ Новый триггер"`, выберите `"appendData"` и задайте триггер на запуск раз в 10 минут.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас функция возвращает "Ljava.lang.Object;@XXX" вместо числовых значений из ячеек A1:A10. Как можно это пофиксить?